# How to show date format in both english and arabic?

Tags: android, date, datetime, simpledateformat, arabic

Hi I want to achieve format of date like this "2021 نوفمبر"
can anybody help me how I can achieve this format?

Here is my sample source code

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", locale);
            dateString = dateFormatter.format(date);
```

Comment: Consider not using `SimpleDateFormat` and related classes since `SImpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. I suggest java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Built-in since API level 26 and available for lower levels through desugaring. See the answer by Nitesh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the Locale to "ar" will convert the date format from English to Arabic.
I have also used `DateTimeFormatter` , as `SimpleDateFormat` is [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)

```
fun parseDate() {
    var formatter: DateTimeFormatter? = null
    val date = "2021-11-03T14:09:31"
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        val dateTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter)
        val formatter2: DateTimeFormatter =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "yyyy, MMM d", Locale("ar")  // set the language in which you want to convert
                                            // For english use Locale.ENGLISH
            )
        Log.e("Date", "" + dateTime.format(formatter2))
    }
}
```

Note: `DateTimeFormatter` only works in android 8 and above, to use it below android 8 enable [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

**Output** : 2021, نوفمبر 3

**Edit:** : If you want to convert numbers also to arabic use `withDecimalStyle` with the `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
 val formatter2: DateTimeFormatter =
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                    "d MMM, yyyy",
                    Locale("ar")
                ).withDecimalStyle(
                    DecimalStyle.of(Locale("ar"))
                )
```

**Output:** ٣ نوفمبر, ٢٠٢١

Comment: Question: Why is only a part of your output in Arabic? A problem? Most Arabic countries use different digits today.

Comment: @MenoHochschild , I have edited any answer and added method to convert digits also to Arabic.

Answer (score 2):

The date language is determined by the system language, but to display the date in specific languages ​​without relying on the system language. You can do like this

```
 TextView arabicText = findViewById(R.id.arabic);
 TextView englishText = findViewById(R.id.english);
    
 Date date = new Date();
    
 SimpleDateFormat arDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", new Locale("ar"));
 SimpleDateFormat enDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", new Locale("en"));
    
 String ar = arDate.format(date);
 String en = enDate.format(date);
    
    
 arabicText.setText(ar);
 englishText.setText(en);
```