# How to get date and time text in arabic format with arabic digits. Android

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, localization, format

The following code return in english format however I want arabic 
currentDate.format(DateFormatter) 
currentTime.format(TimeFormatter)

example: 
expected: ١٢:٠٠  
actual: 12:00

```
...
        var dateString: String = ""
        var timeString: String = ""
...

        val DateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(Locale( "ar"))
        val TimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(Locale( "ar"))

        val currentDate = LocalDate.now()
        val currentTime = LocalTime.now()


        dateString = currentDate.format(DateFormatter)
        timeString = currentTime.format(TimeFormatter)
...
```

Comment: I wrote a answer similar to this sometime ago, you can look into that - [how-to-show-date-format-in-both-english-and-arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065793/how-to-show-date-format-in-both-english-and-arabic/70066026#70066026)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val DateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withDecimalStyle(DecimalStyle.of(Locale("ar")))
val TimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withDecimalStyle(DecimalStyle.of(Locale("ar")))
```